# Tableview with custom cells gets duplicate while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've created an `UITableView` based **"count-down"** timer app, each cell has a **"countdown label"** and a **"start running button"**
The issue is when I press the button, trigger the timer to run,
then I scroll down, the 10th cell gets trigger too.
when I scroll back, the first cell timer gets reset.

After searched it might be the `dequeueReusableCell` part,
but I don't know how to fix it.

all code on github:
https://github.com/evancohi/CountdownTimer

Here is how my `cellForRowAt` method setup

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timerListCellId", for: indexPath) as! TimerListCell

     cell.timerLabel.text = self.timerArray[indexPath.row]
     cell.missionLabel.text = self.missionArray[indexPath.row]

     return cell
 }
```

Can you please give some advices?

Comment: could you provide more info please? in regards to `timerArray` and `missionArray` ? how do they get populated and also where is the timer button? is it in each cell?

Comment: Please give some more details code so one can understand issue and give solution for the same.

Comment: @Sina thank you Sina, tried but not work.

Comment: @HardikThakkar thank you! please check the github link I just added.

Answer (score 0):

UITableview's dequeueReusableCell is used to reuse the tableview cells for smooth scrolling experience. 
So in order to stop you cells from duplicating, you should implement a conditional check in cellForRowAt() method implementation so that you only cells where you have started the timer perform the timer task.

eg.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "timerListCellId", for: indexPath) as! TimerListCell

    cell.timerLabel.text = self.timerArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.missionLabel.text = self.missionArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.isTimerRunning = self.timerArray[indexPath.row]
    if cell.isTimerRunning == true {
       // enable trigger
    }
    else{
     // disable trigger
    }

    return cell
}
```

In above example I have created timerArray which by default contains all 'false' entries. When you start timer for a cell, replace the entry at the same index path.row to 'true' and use this array in cellforRow, for identifying the cell where you have triggered the timer.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav! I do have isTimerRunning condition check on my custom cell, could you take a look of the github link I just added?

Comment: @EvanC i think you need to use class or dictionary for boolean variable

Comment: @EvanC I have checked your code. You have isTimerRunning in TimerListCell class which will not do the job as the cells are getting reused. But you should maintain an array for the running status of all cells in CountdownTimerMainVC.